# Getting Undefined property: projekti when trying to print field fetched from databse

Tags: laravel, database

i get this error Undefined property: projekti
when trying to print a field fetched from database
this is the code that causes the error

```
   @foreach($dataOfProjects as $dp)
 
        <div class="col-md-4 mt-2">
            <h1 class="p-5 border border-3" >{{$dp->projekti}}</h1>
        </div>    
    @endforeach
```

specifically the `{{$dp->projekti}}

this is the controller that is returning the dataOfProjects variable

```
public function specificClub(Request $request,$id){
    $data = Clubs::find($id);
    $dataOfProjects = DB::table('projektet') -> where('klubi', '=',$id);

    $teachers =  DB::table('mesuesit')->join('klubet','klubet.id','=','mesuesit.klubi_ne_kujdesari')->select('mesuesit.emri')->where('klubet.emri','=','rrobotike')->get();//Per te mare emrin e mesuesve te ketij klubi
    return view('specificClub',  compact('data','dataOfProjects','teachers'));
}
```

This is the table klubet
[image]

and this is the table projektet
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `->get()` for multiple results or `->first()` for one result to this line:

```
$dataOfProjects = DB::table('projektet') -> where('klubi', '=',$id);
```

From:

```
$dataOfProjects = DB::table('projektet') -> where('klubi', '=',$id);
```

To (for multiple results):

```
$dataOfProjects = DB::table('projektet')->where('klubi', '=',$id)->get();
```

To (for one results):

```
$dataOfProjects = DB::table('projektet')->where('klubi', '=',$id)->first();
```